# Can I have a nested OR statement within my Ternary If statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am wondering if it is possible to turn this statement of code into a ternary if statement.

```
var placeHolder = await Source.EntityOrDefaultAsync<_Item>(item => item.CompanyID == order.CompanyID && item.ItemID == od.ItemID);

                if (placeHolder.TaxedAllCountryRegions = true || placeHolder.TaxedFed == 1 && placeHolder.TaxedState == 1)
                {
                    decimal.TryParse(placeHolder.HandlingFee, out decimal trueFee);
                    od.HandlingFee = trueFee * od.Quantity;
                }
```

I tried formatting it like this- but don't think it quite works.

```
 var placeHolder = await Source.EntityOrDefaultAsync<_Item>(item => item.CompanyID == order.CompanyID && item.ItemID == od.ItemID);

                return (placeHolder.TaxedAllCountryRegions = true || placeHolder.TaxedFed == 1 && placeHolder.TaxedState == 1) ?
                                                                                                                                decimal.TryParse(placeHolder.HandlingFee, out decimal trueFee)
                                                                                                                                : false;
                od.HandlingFee = trueFee * od.Quantity;
```

Comment: Presumably you meant `== true`?

Comment: You have OR and AND without parens - it might be doing something other than what you meant it to. if (x||y&&z) is not the same as if ((x||y)&z)

Comment: and what canton said: this should be a double equals `placeHolder.TaxedAllCountryRegions == true`

Comment: @Nikki9696 you can't guarantee that. [Assignments return the assigned value](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kmYB0J) and can therefore be tested. Think `while(x=reader.Read() != null)`

Comment: You've got a `return` before that assignment so that's not even going to compile.  I do not think your original logic should be changed.  You only need the conditional operator (or as you call it the ternary) when you have a `if\else` and both assign a value to the same thing.

Comment: There are several inequivalencies in your code - why do you need a ternary statement?  What happens if the parse fails?

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to put the ternary in the wrong place. What should `HandlingFee` be set to if that `if` condition isn't met? In your original code it's not set to anything, which means this is a bad use of a ternary. If it should be set to `0`, say, then you'd write something like `od.HandlingFee = (placeHolder.... || ....&& .... ) ? decimal.Parse(placeHolder.HandlingFee) * od.Quantity : 0`

Comment: You might want to skip the multiplication and assignment if `TryParse` returns `false` though, unless you want the value to be set to 0.

Comment: Either way, ignoring the result of a `TryParse` is a red flag, so I'd either that it's being deliberately ignored, or use its return value still

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us in English what the logic is to be so that we can assess how accurate your conversion is. It is very difficult to know the true intent of the logic if all we have is broken code

Comment: @CaiusJard - yes, you are correct. I made an assumption that for this use case, assignment was not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As canton7 already commented, you might want to use `== true` instead of `= true`. Probably
also the part after `||` must be embedded in parenthesis.

Apart from that, you want also assign the `HandlingFee`, so a conditional operator alone doesn't help. But why dont you use a `bool` variable?

```
bool computeHandlingFee = placeHolder.TaxedAllCountryRegions || (placeHolder.TaxedFed == 1 && placeHolder.TaxedState == 1);
if(computeHandlingFee && decimal.TryParse(placeHolder.HandlingFee, out decimal trueFee))
{
     od.HandlingFee = trueFee * od.Quantity;
}
return computeHandlingFee;
```

Maybe you want to include the `decimal.TryParse` in the `computeHandlingFee`-logic.

Comment: This code is slightly different from the original.  It's possible they actually do want the multiplication and assignment when `TryParse` fails.

Comment: @juharr: the original code contained multiple bugs, so i'm not sure if it's correct in that case. I have (now) also mentioned that he might want to include the TryParse check in the bool-logic, if that's desired.